# How to make all flags being displayed on page load instead of being shown only when :hover - WPML

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have a question and request for a tip, help on how can I make the language flags being displayed with out every time and hover on the flag to see other available flags to klick on ?

I am using WP plugin called WPML and everything is ok, but the other flags are visible only when you hover on the current flag and I would like them to be always displayed on all pages from the start when it loads the website. 
How can I make this possible ??

Here is my website: www.mallnitzapartments.eu

And as wel I am facing issue with displaying all those language flags in SAFARI browser. Any solutions for Safari as well ?

Thanks for help in advance,
B.R.

Answer (score 0):

Solve with css:

```
#lang_sel_click ul > li > ul { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
```